# Pass a property to a component "by reference"

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to make a component that can change a property of another component "by reference".

For example:

```
TextField {
    id: lat
    text: MyDataSource.latitude
}

LatLongButton {
    latitude: lat.text
    // or:
    // latitude: MyDataSource.latitude
}
```

When the user clicks the button, for example, I want to update the value of lat.text. Now the problem is when I create LatLongButton as a component in a separate file:

```
LatLongButton {
    // doesn't work, alias has to be set initially to something
    // property alias latitude: ???
    // overriding it in the main file is also not possible

    property real latitude: 0
    onClicked: {
        // I want this to change some other property indirectly
        // that is, one that I specify in the main file
        latitude = 123
        // but this here doesn't set the value through the binding -
        // it seems to destroy the binding and set the value of this
        // component directly
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achive this? I think there must be, because the builtin widgets like TextField work like this. The user interacts, and then they can change a property *across a binding*.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but if your button fetches the latitude from some backend, then add an invokable method to the backend type that updates the internal latitude and emits a latitudeChanged() signal. Then the TextField's text binding will be updated. Whenever the text is edited via the TextField, respond to the accepted() or editingFinished() signals and set the latitude property of the backend.